# how to store data in non volatile memory

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I'm a beginner in the embedded field. I have done a few engineering project using ARM and PIC micro controller. Now I'm facing a problem how to store some details(like name and rate) in the non volatile memory or external memory? Can any one help me to solve this? Fom where I should get examples of this storing? Now am using keil u vision 4 for programming but `printf` is not working in it? Earlier I'm using keil u vision 3 `printf` was working on that?

Comment: from google you you can get many example.

Comment: This will depend on the hardware.  Is your NVRAM on the PIC itself (in which case, read the manual for that kind of PIC).  If it is on some other chip, you will have to read about that chip.

Comment: sir i'm using arm7 lpc2148 micro controller how i can store and get that data when needed?????

Comment: If you want to store your values in the on-chip flash, you will have to dedicate a page to it.  Look up 'IAP', 'In-Application Programming' in the user manual for the LPC2148.

Answer (score 1):

Various controller families have such things as EEPROM, or modifiable Flash. But they are accessed in a completely controller-dependent way.

To use them, you just issue a command (or rather set of commands) to store data X to address Y in this memory area. Later on, you get them back.

How this is done should be obtainable from the manual and/or application notes from the manufacturer of the chip.

Also be aware of the timing. AFAIR, a PIC needs 4 ms to store a single byte, so it might be helpful to set up (or use) a framework which automatically stores data byte for byte and advances upon receipt of an interrupt. So the work is done in the background.

Comment: from where should i get the details how should i store the data in non_volatile memory?????but this is not in data sheet

Comment: @user3555790 It *must* be in the data sheet. It is _the_ reference of the device, provided by the manufacturer. And as far as I remember, I got the info from there as well. There might as well be an application note.